# How can I apply ng-deep based on condition?

Tags: css, angular

Example -> in parent component

```
<div class="if-this-class-is-applied">
<child></child> 
</div>
```

### if the above class is applied only then it should trigger ng deep for "child component"

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried this .if-this-class-is-applied ::ng-deep?

Answer (score 6):

```
::ng-deep .if-this-class-is-applied > child {
 // Your styles 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do. Lets say you have a structure like below

```
<div>
   <child [ngClass]="{ 'your-class-name': condition }"></child> 
</div>
```

In css you can alter the child component class like

```
.your-class-name {
  ::ng-deep {
    .child-component-class-you-want-to-alter {
       max-width: 340px;
      }
    }
  }
```

This will only set the max-width based on the condition.